# Google Docs: images are blurry when downloaded the doc as web page

Tags: google-docs, images

I am having a Google Doc with good quality images. Later once my document is completed I have downloaded the web-page (HTML, zipped) version.

When I saw the images in the folder they are of poor quality than what I have uploaded.

I have uploaded image of size 870kb but I got the same image in web page as 337kb

How can set this thing. Based on this I was doing my work. Now this will create major problem.